# How to execute a command at exact time once a day in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, scheduled-tasks, pytz

I am working on a Django web based project in which i need to build a application which work in the following sequence:

1)  user open a page in which he need to enter a `command` and a `time`

2)  Django application will execute that command at a given time on each day till user off the scheduler (by default it is True)

What i am facing the problem is that :

1) How should i execute the commands on a time but on each day. To save the commands and time i created a following model in my `models.py`

```
class commands(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    command = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    execution_time = models.DateField()
```

I have the same time but i am not getting the right way to execute it on each day at the given time

and is it possible to do with `pytz` library?

For executing the commands i am using `paramiko` library

PS: I don't want to use any external library

Comment: @Maulwurfn I think that cron is a libray?

Comment: cron is installed since three decades on every unix system

Comment: I don't know much about but what about the windows server?

Comment: Did you mention Windows Server?

Comment: There'd have to be a really good reason not to use cron or similar (at on winders). Not a wheel you want to rush to reinvent this.

Comment: You say you are using `paramiko` to run commands, but you also don't want to use any external libraries? Isn't `paramiko` an external library?

Comment: Instead of paramiko i am also using pytz. I prefer not to add more :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you could have your django app add and remove cron jobs on the system, another more django-ish approach would be to use [Celery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery/). It is a task queue system that can run both synch and async tasks.

One specific feature of Celery is scheduled tasks: http://packages.python.org/celery/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

```
from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "runs-every-30-seconds": {
        "task": "tasks.add",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=30),
        "args": (16, 16)
    },
}
```

They also have a more granular version of the period task that replicates the scheduling of a crontab:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 A.M
    'every-monday-morning': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        'args': (16, 16),
    },
}
```

Celery by itself is stand-alone but there is the [django-celery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery/) specific verison

The benefit of this solution is that you do not need to edit and maintain a system-level cron tab. This is a solution that is highly integrated into django for this exact use.

Also a **huge** win over using a cron is that Celery can scale with your system. If you were using a basic system crontab, then the tasks would be located on the server that hosts the application. But what if you needed to ramp up your site and run it on 5 web application nodes? You would need to centralize that crontab. If you are using Celery, you have a [large number of options](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html) for how to transport and store tasks. It is inherently distributed, and available in sync to all your application servers. It is portable.

Comment: How should i add the task. For example to execute a task i have to call a function i.e. *** sample_test(user, commands) *** . I mena how should i add in the above code ?

Comment: On more question, As you defined the *** day_of_week** . What should i make changes to execute it on monday and wednesday or all of days in a week? Just asking for an example because i go through the given template but didn't find this  :)

Comment: I think this link might be helpful for [dynamically adding periodic tasks](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/celery-users/CZXCh8sCK5Q), but in your case you will want to use `CrontabSchedule` instead of `IntervalSchedule`

Comment: And for the other question, you can specify `day_of_week` as a list to say what days. If you do not set this attribute at all, it is every day of the week:  (Mon/Wed) `crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=[1,3])` , or every day at 7:30:  `crontab(hour=7, minute=30)`

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the proper way to do this would be write a [Django custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands) and execute it via cron. But you seem to be under luck as others have felt similar need and have written custom django apps. Take [django-cron](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for your problem is standard `cron` application (task planner on *nix systems). You can schedule a script using cron (by adding it to crontab).

If your script must perform in you Django application environment, it's possible to tell him to do that with `setup_environment` function. You can read more about standalone scripts for Django applications [here](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/).